# Removing Tailwind CSS blur-sm class does (mostly) nothing in Safari

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, stimulusjs

I have a list of paragraphs translated in both French and English. And I also have several buttons the user can click to blur/unblur the French or English text.

For example, here is the function that gets triggered when users click on the "Blur French text" button:

```
unblurFrenchPhrases() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.french-phrase').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('blur-sm'));
    }
```

It works great in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. In Safari, the Tailwind class gets removed as expected but the text still appears blurred unless I click on it or select it.

Same if I type this in the JavaScript console directly:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.french-phrase').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('blur-sm'));
```

What am I doing wrong? My guess is that this isn't the right way of removing a Tailwind class to manipulate the DOM but I'm not sure what to do instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. The elements I was trying to blur/unblur also had a "drop-shadow-md" class. After removing, everything is working in Safari. Not sure if it's a bug or blur and drop-shadow are not meant to be used this way.